# Decoding UTF16LE with Encoding.Unicode garbles text

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding

I have the following code:

```cs
var reader = new StreamReader(inputSubtitle, encoding);
string str;
var list = new List<String>();
try
{
    str = reader.ReadLine();
    while (str != null)
    {
        list.Add(str);
        str = reader.ReadLine();
    }
    return list;
}
```

The encoding is based on the Byte Order Mark. The charset detector code (can provide it if necessary) simply looks at the hex value of the first couple of bytes in the file. The files are usually UTF-8, Windows ANSI (Codepage-1252) or UTF-16LE. The last one currently fails, and I have no clue why.

Previewing the text in Notepad says it's encoded as Unicode (with which it means UTF-16LE, afaik), opening in Firefox says it's UTF-16LE and the BOM starts with bytes FF FE.

Take this example text:

```
1
00:04:05,253 --> 00:04:11,886
<i>This is the first line</i>
- This is the second line.
```

I send this file as a filestream to the charset detector (I use filestream as an input in the backend), where I added the following debug line:

```cs
byte[] dataFromFileStream = new byte[(input.Length)];
input.Read(dataFromFileStream, 0, (int)input.Length);
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(dataFromFileStream));
```

This produces the following hexcode:

`"FF-FE-31-00-(...)"`

FF-FE is the Byte Order Mark of UTF16-LE.

Opening this hexcode with the `StreamReader` and encoding set to `Encoding.Unicode` turns the data into a single string:

`"\u0d00\u0a00　　㨀　㐀㨀　㔀Ⰰ㈀㔀㌀ ⴀⴀ㸀 　　㨀　㐀㨀\u3100\u3100Ⰰ㠀㠀㘀\u0d00\u0a00㰀椀㸀吀栀椀猀 椀猀 琀栀攀 昀椀爀猀琀 氀椀渀攀㰀⼀椀㸀\u0d00\u0a00ⴀ 吀栀椀猀 椀猀 琀栀攀 猀攀挀漀渀搀 氀椀渀攀⸀"`

Setting the encoder to `Encoding.GetEncoding(1201)`, e.g. as a UTF-16BE, opens the file properly and decodes it to 4 lines in the list, as expected.

I noticed this bug since a couple of weeks, before then the code worked properly. Is it something that happened in an update? `Encoding.Unicode` is described as UTF-16LE in the documentation.

I changed my code to use UTF-16BE as decoder for the moment to make it work again, but that just feels wrong.

Comment: It would help if you could provide a [mcve] - hard code a small amount of binary data into the program. (Perhaps your file is actually somewhat broken, and is a mixture of big-endian and little-endian?)

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet when I wrote some short code in a single file to make the problem more readable I discovered my mistake. I changed my question to show my solution for this "error" and an explanation why using a different charset worked.

Comment: Please add the solution and the explanation [as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), instead of adding it to the question. You can also [accept your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/), but you must wait 48 hours to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I made a stupid mistake; the Charset detector reads a couple of bytes to determine the encoding of the file. To make sure I have a UTF-16LE file (which starts with FF-FE) and not a UTF-32LE (which starts with FF-FE-00-00) I read the third byte as well. After reading those bytes, however, *I did not reset the position of the FileStream back to 0.* An earlier version of my code, with a different constructor, did reset the starting position. Adding the code for resetting the position fixed it.

**Explanation:**
The StreamReader class does not necessarily need a BOM in a UTF file, so it starts reading from the position left after the charset detector did its thing. Detecting UTF-8 or ANSI made no issues, since those are encoded in single bytes. UTF-16 uses two bytes for each character, so starting at an odd numbered byte caused everything to look like reversed byte order for the reader. Therefore decoding like UTF-16BE 'fixed' the issue.